# Numerical Analysis: Why this function is giving Sage / WolframAlpha so much trouble to integrate?

Tags: numerical-methods

I am trying to find the numerical value of $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(2\cos\theta)\cos(4\theta)\,d\theta$$.

The integrand looks like a nice, continuous function that is finite, bounded, differentiable, etc. Furthermore, I am just looking for a numerical value, not the exact antiderivative.

However, upon trying out first with WolframAlpha and Sage, none are able to give a satisfactory numerical value.

WolframAlpha ran out of computation time, and Sage gave an answer of order $10^{-17}$ with an error of order $10^{-15}$, i.e. the error is larger than the answer itself.

I am not an expert in numerical analysis, so I am puzzled at why this happened?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Bonus: If anyone can tell me what is the numerical value (just accurate to 3 significant figures will be enough), I will upvote and accept your answer gratefully.

Comment: $10^{-17}$ with an error of $10^{-15}$ suggests to me that it equals $0.$

Comment: @Moo Which software did you use to get that?

Comment: Mathematica will give you an answer that is satisfactory to any precision you choose.

Comment: WolframAlpha swiftly returns and says zero. You must have made a typo.

Comment: W|A gives the answer for me just fine https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sin(2cos(x))cos(4x)+from+-pi+to+pi

Comment: If you want a quick and dirty way to suppress Mathematica's "help I can't integrate this", just add a constant to the integrand and subtract it at the end. `NIntegrate[Sin[2 Cos[t]] Cos[4 t] + 1, {t, -Pi, Pi}] - 2 Pi`

Comment: I launched WolframAlpha with `NIntegrate[Sin[2 Cos[t]] Cos[4 t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]`, the answer was shown almost immediately. The analytical version `Integrate[Sin[2 Cos[t]] Cos[4 t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]` is also quite fast to show the resulting zero. I do not know where the problem comes from - either bad internet connection, or a quick bugfix on server side (doubt that).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The integrand $f(\theta):=\sin(2\cos\theta)\cos(4\theta)$ is an even function: $f(-\theta)=f(\theta)$. So the integral of $f$ over the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is double its value over $[0,\pi]$. However, check also that 
$$f\left(\frac\pi2+t\right)=-f\left(\frac\pi2-t\right),$$
i.e. the integrand has odd symmetry around the point $(\pi/2,0)$. Hence the integral equals zero.

Comment: Nice. Triumph of human over machine.

Comment: @yoyostein: A lot of triumphs of human over machine are merely examples of "The computer did what you asked it to, not what you wanted it to".

Answer (score 17):

The graph of the function makes it obvious:[image]

Comment: It doesn't quite. We are all used to _odd_ functions integrating to zero. But this one becomes odd only if moved by $\pi/2$. So at the first glance the graph makes it even stranger, not obvious.

Comment: I meant the regions above and below the X axis are identical.